# THREE.js performance when creating vectors

Tags: javascript, three.js

At the moment I am working a lot with WebVR, so performance is really crucial.

In THREE.js it is usually advised that you don't create new Vectors in update loops but to reuse it. As I dont like anonymously encapsulated functions which return your actual function, I was thinking of a easy-to-use replacement that is still performant.

And I came up with

```
  window.vectors = {}
  window.vector = (name) => {
    if (vectors.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
      return vectors[name]
    } else {
      let vec = new THREE.Vector3;
      vectors[name] = vec;
      return vec
    }
  }
```

That way you don't have to create Vectors at all but just call

```
vector('vectorname').fromArray(...)
```

Do you think is a smart way to handle them? I already did a quick benchmark on jsben.ch and the speed of 1000 lookups was only 10% lower than reusing a single one, and almost twice as fast as creating new ones.

So to all THREE.js devs out there: how are you handling this? Does it make sense how I do it or can you think of caveats (except theoretically being able to add keys beyond the Objects maximum)?

Comment: How long would you cache them for?

Comment: as WebVR scenes tend to crash Firefox quite frequently - not very long, but always only for the current session I guess. Also I wont need any more than maybe 30 of those, so I don't think that they would be garbage collected at all...